# How to save login data with shared_preferences?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can someone help me how to correct save login data with shared_preferences?

When I type login and pass to fields and then quit the app, I cannot back to main_screen, it shows auth screen.

Main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final _loginData = preferences.getString('loginData');
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: _loginData == null ? AuthWidget() : MainScreenWidget(),
      routes: {
        '/auth': (context) => AuthWidget(),
        '/main_screen': (context) => MainScreenWidget(),
        '/evroko_standart_screen': (context) => EvrokoStandartScreen(),
        '/evroko_vip_screen': (context) => EvrokoVipScreen(),
        '/oskanova_screen': (context) => OskanovaScreen(),
        '/oskanova_premium_screen': (context) => OskanovaPremiumScreen(),
        '/message_screen': (context) => Message_screen(),
        '/map_screen': (context) => MapScreen(),
        '/reservation_screen': (context) => Reservation_screen(),
      },
      initialRoute: '/auth',
    ),
  );
}
```

Code from auth widget screen:

```
Future<dynamic> fetchData() async {
      final loginUser = loginUserText.text;
      final passUser = passwordUserText.text;
      if (passUser == '') {
        _showMyDialog();
      } else {
        final urlAuth = Uri.parse('$kUrl/api/users/$loginUser/$passUser/valid');
        final response = await http.get(urlAuth,
            headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
        Map<String, dynamic> parsed = json.decode(response.body);
        final user = User.fromJson(parsed);
        if (user.httpStatusCode == 200 && user.result!.result == 0) {
          userId = (user.result!.userId)!.toInt();
          userName = (user.result!.name)!.toString();
          final urlBalance = Uri.parse('$kUrl/api/users/$userId/balance');
          final responseBalance = await http.get(urlBalance,
              headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});
          Map<String, dynamic> parsedBalance =
              json.decode(responseBalance.body);
          final userBalanceData = Balance.fromJson(parsedBalance);
          SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          preferences.setString('loginData', userName!);
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/main_screen');
          userBalance = userBalanceData.result!.deposits;
          userPoints = userBalanceData.result!.points;
        } else {
          _showMyDialog();
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered using a `Stateful Widget` as your home screen and update it based on the value from shared preferences?

Comment: Maybe it is because `MaterialWidget`'s `initialRoute` is '/auth'.

Comment: If I disable initialRoute its show main_screen

Comment: What about removing `home` and using `initialRoute: _loginData == null ? '/auth' : '/main_screen'`?

Comment: Not working like should be. I enter the login and pass and enter the main screen. When clode and open app its show mainscreen, but username is Null

Comment: Stateless widgets are not mutable, they will only built once and will not reflect changes of `_loginData` variable.

Comment: You said username is null. Is there a difference between _loginData and username? Because if you set `initialRoute` as `_loginData == null ? '/auth' : '/main_screen'`, initial screen will be `AuthWidget` if `_loginData` is null.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Yes, using a stateful widget is better method. But the code already changes screen by `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('/main_screen');` line after loginData preference is set. I think the problem is caused by something different.

Answer (score 0):

Use `home` instead of `initialRoute`. Since you are not having a default `/` route that flutter has and in the home property add your logic for `_loginData == null ? AuthWidget() : MainScreenWidget()`

PS. also move your `MaterialApp` to a new StatelessWidget of StatefulWidget class.